# Inequality with natural numbers - how to find a solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

Assume $z,y\in\mathbb{N}$ where $z\geq y$.  I want to prove that there exists $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:

$ 2z > x \geq z $

where $y$ divides x.

I've tried for some cases and it seems to hold. How to solve this? Or more general/important how to solve these kinds of problems?

Comment: Are you sure about your statement? Take $z=y=0$.

Comment: @5xum For me, $\mathbb{N}=\left\{0,1,2,3,\cdots \right\}$. But your example is perfect.

Comment: I added the extra condition that $y$ should divide x.

Comment: and 0 is not contained in my definition of $\mathbb{N}$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The candidate values for $x$ are $z,z+1, z+2,\dots, z+(z-1)$

Take a look at the remainder of these values when divided by $y$, i.e.
$$z \bmod y, (z+1) \bmod y, (z+2) \bmod y,\dots, (2z-1) \bmod y.$$

The numbers in this list can only take $y$ different values and they increase by $1$ until hitting $y$, at which point they fall to $0$. Because there are $z$ of them, the fall to $0$ must happen somewhere.

Comment: You can use `\bmod` for "binary mod". =)

Comment: This was a very simple approach: Just write down the candidates and then consider the residue classes - I'll do this next time I encounter such a problem, thanks!

Comment: @guestguest Well, it may not work the next time, but here, this "quasi-pidgeonhole" principle works quite well.